# Find the result of multiplying the entered numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

A program to input (n) number :

- First, I print the cube from each negative entry number
- But the problem with step two is I'm trying to multiply numbers together and print the result

  ```
  x=int(input("Enter number: "))
  n=0
  while x:
      if x<0 :
          s=x**3
          print(s)
      if x==0 :
          s=x
          print(s)
      else :
          s=x
          print(s)
      x=int(input("Enter number: "))
  ```

Comment: Think about the steps you need to take and describe those steps in words. I suggest you write "multiply all the input numbers" as a separate program first.

Comment: just input (int) numbers in the var (x)

Comment: brother..I need the two orders in one Script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is a Python training that exists in many curricula that I have seen before

**i think that is what do you want**

```
mmult = 1
x = int (input("Enter number: "))
while True :
    if x < 0 :
        s = x **3
        print (s)
    if mmult != 0 :
        mmult =  mmult * x
        print (mmult)
    else:
        mmult = x
        print (mmult)
    x = int(input("Enter number: "))
```

Comment: Why don't you just initialize `mmult` to `1` so you don't need to test it?

Comment: For the first time in the loop

Comment: But if you initialize to 1, `mmult * x` is the same as `x`, so it does the right thing without testing.

Comment: Yes that is all right, I will edit my answer